# Camel DSL - Reuse transformation logic defined via Blueprint DSL in different routes

Tags: apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

I want to reuse transformation steps defined by blueprint DSL in different camel routes but couldn't find out how to achieve this.

Let's give an example here:

```
    <camelContext id="jms-context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <route id="inputAqTest8">
            <from id="_fromAqTest8" uri="aqTest8:queue:QUELOGENTRY"/>
            <!-- some complicated transformation here -->
            <to id="_to1" uri="umChannel:topic:Input"/>
        </route>
        <route id="inputAqTest12">
            <from id="_fromAqTest12" uri="aqTest12:queue:QUEPOSTDATA"/>
            <!-- some complicated transformation here -->
            <to id="_to2" uri="umChannel:topic:Input"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
```

I already optimized this by moving the transformation and the delivery to an own route connected by the direct component.

```
    <camelContext id="jms-context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <route id="inputAqTest8">
            <from id="_fromAqTest8" uri="aqTest8:queue:QUELOGENTRY"/>
            <to id="_to1" uri="direct:process"/>
        </route>
        <route id="inputAqTest12">
            <from id="_fromAqTest12" uri="aqTest12:queue:QUEPOSTDATA"/>
            <to id="_to2" uri="direct:process"/>
        </route>
        <route id="process">
            <from id="_from1" uri="direct:process"/>
            <!-- some complicated transformation here -->
            <to id="_to" uri="umChannel:topic:Input"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
```

This perfectly reuses the transformation logic. But since direct synchronizes the 'calls' the routes are no longer independent. Also, I now have only one producer slowing down since no parallel delivery of the transformed messages can happen (this is also the reason why I didn't want to merge all into a single route).

So how can I get the best of both approaches - reuse the definition of the transformation and keep the routes independent? Thanks in advance for your ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not correct about direct, its just like a java method call so you can call the route concurrently from each route, its just using the calling thread.

So what you have done with separating that transformer logic into a route and call it using direct is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the transformation logic extracted in a java class and  have that java class as a spring prototype bean and use an instance of that bean in each one of your routes. I am quite sure it will do the work

```
<bean id="myBean" scope="pototype" class="com.my.org.MyComplexTransformation/>

 <route id="inputAqTest8">
        <from id="_fromAqTest8" uri="aqTest8:queue:QUELOGENTRY"/>
        <bean ref="myBean"/>
        <to id="_to1" uri="umChannel:topic:Input"/>
 </route>
 <route id="inputAqTest12">
        <from id="_fromAqTest12" uri="aqTest12:queue:QUEPOSTDATA"/>
        <bean ref="myBean"/>
        <to id="_to2" uri="umChannel:topic:Input"/>
 </route>
```